# Server with multiple connections

Tags: java, networking, concurrency, client

I have a server S, and there may be two types of clients. Type A and B. Type A clients can communicate with type B clients only through S(A sends a message to S, then S sends it to B). A client A, can't communicate with another A, neither do B with another B.

Supposing that I have two A clients, 1A and 2A and both want to send a message to client B at the same time, how should I make it so that they don't overlap? This is so that S receives both the messages in sepparate instances and B receives them as well.

Comment: There are many ways to solve this problem. What have you tried?

Comment: I have 2 clients that communicate with each other through a server, and I wondered how should I do it to have more than 1 set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using threads to implement S, which is the norm in Java, this is a problem of **thread-safety.** The problem you want to avoid is intermixing two messages. This must be achieved by making sending a message from S, a thread-safe operation - and in particular, an *atomic* operation with respect to other such messages.

Comment: Not really. You only need to make sending a message from S *to any specific client* thread-safe. Basically, synchronize on the output stream.